# Why isn't my cronjob running?

Tags: linux, centos, cron, pam, selinux

I have a cronjob in `/etc/cron.d/mycron` that looks like this:

`0 3 * * *         apache    php /path/to/my/script.php`

In the same file there are other cronjobs begin run as root and other users (which work), but for some reason this job running as apache isn't running and isn't reporting anything in `/var/log/messages` or sending anything to the `MAILTO` address in the cron file. When I `su apache` and run the cronjob's command, it works fine, but cron doesn't like it.

This is a long running problem for me and so far I have gathered the following possibilities:

- The apache user doesn't have a home directory (the other cron users do), and crond doesn't like this.
- There's some PAM or `/etc/security/access.conf` setting blocking apache using crond, although `/etc/security/access.conf` is completely commented out.
- SELinux - this is usually the culprit when a problem seems really weird.

Any ideas or experience with this problem and what the solution might be?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see anything in `/var/log/cron`?

Comment: What are the ownership and permissions on the file ?

Comment: Is the cron daemon running?

Comment: `$ service crond status` ... `crond (pid  28490) is running...`. Also, the file perms are `664`, but since I can log in as apache myself and run the command manually this cannot be the issue.

Comment: There's no mention of the cronjob in `/var/log/cron`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try using full path for php in cron config: `/usr/bin/php`
- Check apache home directory: `grep apache /etc/passwd` As far as I know, user should always have home directory. It may reside not in /home.
- Check syslog messages about security events. If this is PAM, you'll see something
- Try disabling SELinux

Comment: Found it. `(CRON) ERROR chdir failed (/home/apache): No such file or directory`. Cron users need a home dir.

Answer (score 6):

A home directory must be set for the user. If the user doesn't have one, you can specify it directly in the cron.d-file.

You probably need to provide PATH=/usr/bin/ too, or specify full path for the command.

```
HOME=/tmp
0 3 * * *         apache    /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

`cron` by default runs with a very limited `PATH`; do you need to put in the full path to the `php` binary?

Comment: For simplicity I removed the full path when I posted on here - but yes, the actual cronjob is `0 3 * * *         apache    /usr/local/bin/php -c /etc/php.ini       /path/to/my/script.php`